# "WordPress database error". Cant send data with my post request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to send an ajax post request to fetch some data from my database. But I cant seem to send the right data (in this case the country name) to my ajax hook.

js code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            action: 'country_from',
            selected_from: selected_from
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("data " + data);
        },
    });
```

Php ajax hook

```
function country_from(){
    global $wpdb;
    $country_from_data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `ringa` WHERE land = selected_from", ARRAY_A);
    echo json_encode($country_from_data);
    wp_die();
}
```

My connection and everything works. But I cant send over the `selected_from` variable from from my js code to my action hook.

When I try this code, I get this error code in my ajax request.

```
WordPress database error: [Unknown column 'selected_from' in 'where clause']
SELECT * FROM `ringa` WHERE land = selected_from
```

So basicly how do I "send" over the `selected_from` so that I can use it in my sql statement?

Comment: Ugh, so stupid of me.. Thanks! I still get this error though: `WordPress database error: [Unknown column 'USA' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Yeah that worked, thx! Yes. I will sanatise the input now. Just wanted to get it to work first :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `selected_from` is a variable, not a column/string. So it needs to be accessed as `$_POST['selected_from']`, it then needs to be quoted because it will be a string when it gets to the DB.

```
$country_from_data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `ringa` WHERE land = '$_POST['selected_from']'", ARRAY_A);
```

That will work occasionally, if a single quote is present it will fail. It also opens you to SQL injections. You should use parameterized queries, I don't know WP but they should have some function for it.

Something like:

```
$country_from_data = $wpdb->prepare??("SELECT * FROM `ringa` WHERE land = ?", ARRAY_A);
$country_from_data->execute(array($_POST['selected_from']));
```

This is PDO syntax, you'll need to find what WP actual uses.